# Color rows after even / odd row selectors in css

Tags: html, css

given a table

```
<table>
<tr class="sechead">...
<tr>...
<tr>... 
<tr class="sechead">...
<tr>...
<tr>...
</table>
```

I have tried the following. I want it to alternate the colours for the rows coming after sechead.

```
table tr.sechead:nth-child(even) ~ tr{background-color:rgb(75,172,198);}
table tr.sechead:nth-child(odd) ~ tr{background-color:rgb(153,129,189);}
```

It color all the rows with the same color. Any possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all of the rows after the `.sechead` come after the first `.sechead`

If adjusting the HTML is okay, you could try this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sechead">...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sechead">...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
  ...
</table>
```

Then your style can be:

```
tbody > tr {background-color:rgb(75,175,198);}
tbody:nth-child(even) > tr {background-color:rgb(153,129,189);}
```

Note that I removed the "odd" selector, so that browsers that don't support `nth-child` still have a fallback defined.

Comment: Its fine. I have one problem, that my CMS system do not alow me to create a table like that without going into source view.(fine for me, but not for customers. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your sure you have only two `<tr>` tags after every `class="sechead"` . Then u can try this

```
<table>
<tr class="sechead"><td>Hello</td></tr>
<tr><td>content1</td></tr>
<tr><td>content2</td></tr>
<tr class="sechead"><td>welcome</td></tr>
<tr><td>content4</td></tr>
<tr><td>content5</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
<style>
tr{width:50px;height:30px;}
table tr.sechead + tr{background-color:rgb(75,172,198);}
table tr.sechead + tr+tr{background-color:rgb(153,129,189);}
</style>
```